# Paypal mobile payment in Android to any user

Tags: android, paypal

I am trying to build an Android app to make payments to users' friends (Paypal personal accounts), not to the app owner's business account. Is there a way to do this? I can only found examples for this for building web sites. Android apps examples I've found are for paying to a fixed business account.

Comment: So you are trying to create a competitor to Venmo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venmo which is owned by PayPal?

Comment: No. I am not. Payment is only part of my app.